# Prove that points A, B, K and L lie on a circle $c$

Tags: analytic-geometry

In an acute-angled triangle ABC with height CD, K and L are orthogonal projections through D respectively on AC and BC. Prove that points A, B, K and L lie on a circle $c$.

I tried to prove that triangles ADK and DLB are of the same form, but without any luck.

Comment: Hint: the circle will have diameter $AB$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you are claiming that $KA=KB$ or $KA=LA$, then this isn't correct.

Comment: @Wojowu The only hit I've got is "All points of which the distance to two given points is a fixed ratio, lie on a circle."

Comment: Can you use the fact that the circumcenter of a right triangle is the midpoint of the hypotenuse? If so, consider circumcircles of $ABK$ and $ABL$ and prove these are equal.

Comment: @Wojowu I am not sure what you mean. How do you come to the conclusion that ABK and ABL are right triangles?

Comment: Wojowu, I think you misread the problem. $K$ and $L$ are projections of $D$ on $AC$ and $BC$, not the projections of the vertices.

Comment: Ah, I'm really sorry, I have misread the problem. In this case I don't think it's necessarily true that $AB$ will be the diameter.

Comment: You can show that $CK \cdot CA = CD^2 = CL \cdot CB$. This implies that $\frac{CA}{CB} = \frac{CL}{CK}$ thus $\triangle CBA \sim \triangle CKL$

Comment: Suppose that I have proved the equal forms between CBA and CKL, I still don't see how this helps me to prove that A, B, K and L lie on a circle c. I don't find the hit I got from the book helpful at all (see one of my previous posts). I would appreciate a solution upon which I could see where do I need to work towards.

Comment: Actually they're not congruent but similar. From the similarity you get $\angle CBA = \angle CKL$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to prove the following equalities and conclude from there:

$$\angle KAB=\angle CDK=\angle CLK$$

Answer (score 0):

First notice that the $\angle CDK=\angle CBA$ because $\angle BKD$ and $\angle CDB$ are both $\pi/2$. For the same reason $\angle CDL=\angle CAB$. From this follows that $$\angle LDK=\angle CDK+\angle CDL=\angle CBA+\angle CAB$$ therefore $$\angle LDK+\angle ACB=\angle CBA+\angle CAB+\angle ACB=\pi.$$
This implies that the points $C,L,D,K$ lie in the same circle. Hence 
$$\angle DKL= \angle DCL.$$ Now notice that
$$\angle LKB+\angle CAB=\angle DKL+\pi/2+\angle CAB=\angle DCL+\pi/2+\angle CAB$$
and from the fact that $\angle DCB+\angle DBC=\pi/2$ we get 
$$\angle LKB+\angle CAB=\angle DCL+\angle DCB+\angle DBC+\angle CAB=\pi.$$
So $\angle LKB+\angle CAB=\pi$ and $A,L,K,B$ lie in the same circle.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}{} B⟂AB & BE∩KD={E} \\ AF⟂AB & AF∩DL={F} \\ \end{array}$

$ΔCDL∼ΔADF$

$\begin{array}{} \frac{CD}{DL}=\frac{DF}{AF} & ⇒ & AF=\frac{DL·DF}{CD} \end{array}$

$ΔCAD∼ΔBDE$

$\begin{array}{} \frac{CD}{AD}=\frac{BD}{BE} & ⇒ & BE=\frac{AD·BD}{CD} \end{array}$

$ΔADF∼ΔBDL$

$\begin{array}{} \frac{AD}{DF}=\frac{DL}{BD} & ⇒ & AD·BD=DL·DF \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} AF=BE & ⇒ AE=BF & (ΔABE≅ΔABF)  \end{array}$

(angle in a semicircle): right triangles:

$\begin{array}{} ΔAKE, ΔABE & AE \text{(diameter)} & \overset{\Huge\frown}{AKBE}  \\ ΔABF, ΔBLF & BF\text{(diameter)} & \overset{\Huge\frown}{BLAF}  \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} AE∩BF=M & \text{(Parallelogram Diagonals Theorem)}  \end{array}$

semicircles ($\overset{\LARGE\frown}{AKE}$ and $\overset{\LARGE\frown}{BLF})$ with congruent diameters ($AE = BF$) and common centers (midpoint $M$) are arcs contained in circle $M$ (circle $AKLB$)

[image: circleKLB]